# How to login to Ubuntu 13.10 Automatically?

Tags: login, 13.10

I just installed Ubuntu 13.10 with the full disk encryption option selected. This asks me for a password before Ubuntu even starts. I figure since I am already entering one password I could automatically login skipping the login password, however, this option does not seem to exist anymore. Is this feature gone or is it disabled because of the encryption or what?

Answer (score 2):

**Encrypt my home folder**

> This option provides you with an added layer of security. Your home
>   folder is where your personal ﬁles are stored.
>
> By selecting this option, Ubuntu will automatically enable encryption
>   on your home folder, meaning that ﬁles and folders must be decrypted
>   using your password before they can be accessed.
>
> Therefore if someone had physical access to your hard drive (for
>   example, if your computer was stolen and the hard drive removed), they
>   would not be able to see your ﬁles without knowing your password.

**If you choose this option, be careful not to enable automatic login at a later date.
It will cause complications with your encrypted home folder, and will potentially
lock you out of important ﬁles.**

See Page 18 of the [Ubuntu Manual](http://files.ubuntu-manual.org/manuals/getting-started-with-ubuntu/13.10/en_US/screen/Getting%20Started%20with%20Ubuntu%2013.10.pdf).

Comment: Thanks. I don't see in the manual the options I had selected earlier to use LVM and I guess its whole disk encryption. Can I select the first encryption method (whole disk) and then enable automatic login? Where can I find out about these two options?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, just found it. I would like to say the manual only says you can do it when you first install but doesn't explain how to do it after the install has been completed. Please use the following steps in order to succeed!

Click the `Gear` (top right corner)--> `System Settings`-->`User Accounts`-->`Unlock` (top right corner)-->`Automatic Login` (Click to off)--> `Lock` Settings back